# How to check for existence of artifact before publishing in SBT

Tags: scala, build, sbt, artifactory

I'm setting up the build for an SBT project and it would greatly simplify things if SBT could check for the existence of an artifact (jars in particular) with the same name/version, before attempting to upload (to Artifactory), and fail only if that artifact both exists and is different from the one built locally.

The best solution I have at this point is to make `publish` depend on `publishLocal`, and make `skip in publish := true` if the `.sha1` file in the ivy cache matches the one already uploaded. However, manually downloading that file and finding the local one feels very hacky, and I still don't quite know how to work out the timing. Also, is it actually possible to set `skip in publish` after `publishLocal` has run?

If there's a better way to do this, please fill me in!

Answer (score 0):

The most appealing solution I've come to so far is to use

`publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file",  file("dist"))`

and then manually compare checksums and publish conditionally outside of SBT with curl or python's `requests` module.